# Mark ItemViewModel as dirty explicitly

Tags: tornadofx

I have address editor fragment, after user edit address I save changed model values to a database

```
fun saveAddressTable(tableViewEditModel: TableViewEditModel<Client>) {
    tableViewEditModel.items.asSequence()
        .filter { it.value.isDirty }
        .forEach {
            //do stuff }
}
```

Some adressess have obvious mistakes I can fix programmatically, however model is not marked as dirty after I change it.

For example,

```
fun autoEditAddressTable(tableViewEditModel: TableViewEditModel<Client>) {

    tableViewEditModel.items.asSequence()
        .forEach {
            val client = it.value.item
            client.localProperty.value = client.local.replace(",{2,}".toRegex(), ",")
        }
}
```

Changes reflected in the UI, but model itself is not dirty. I've found markDirty() property method, but it doesn't help much. As model is not marked dirty, it fails filter criteria on save.

```
    center = tableview ( controller.clients ) {

        column("Local Address", Client::localProperty)
                .prefWidth(400.0)
                .makeEditable()

        bindSelected(controller.clientModel)
        enableDirtyTracking()
        tableViewEditModel = editModel
    }
```

Isn't TableViewEditModel expected to trace all model alteration? If client edits Local Address column manually, model becomes dirty.

Comment: Can you post a minimal working example so I can debug it?